# Why cast return value of len to int in Python?

Tags: python

In the source code of [Stable Baselines3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3), in `common/preprocessing.py`, on line 158, there is: `return (int(len(observation_space.nvec)),)`.

As far as I know, in Python, `len` can only return an int, and regardless if this is not true, would return an int here (might be wrong on both counts). If this is the case, the cast to int would not make sense to me.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `len` can only return an int, yeah. If `observation_space.nvec.__len__` returned a non-int, [you'd get an error](/a/59604139/4518341). I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Just a terminology sidenote, `int(...)` isn't really a cast. It's just an ordinary function call. And arguably casting has a different meaning in Python, i.e. `cast(int, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `int` is not necessary.

`len` always returns an `int`. If a class' `__len__` implemention returns something other than an `int`, Python will attempt to convert it to an `int`. If that can't be done, a `TypeError` will be raised. There's no scenario where `len` can return something other than an `int`.

You can try to violate this yourself:

```
class Foo:
    def __len__(self):
        return "bad"

>>> len(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```